# Cannot create a File on Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I cannot create a new File on Tomcat server here is a picture of the problem:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Reading is no Problem but overwriting the file is. Im confused why I cant get it to work! Also new File() is executed on Windows if you wonder.

Edit: I resolved it. I was accessing it in my Program Files folder. I moved the Tomcat folder to my Desktop and I can now write to it.

Comment: Probably the un-unescaped `%20` left over in the file name.  However, this is a really bad idea anyway, as you are trying to write to a location that may not exist if the application is deployed as a .war file.  Use the system properties to find an allowed temporary directory outside the application's hierarchy instead.

Comment: Verify  that the file that you're trying to read exists. If it does then it's probably locked by Tomcat as it's being read by your WAR file and that's why you can't write to it. If it does not then it means WAR file has not been exploded (extracted) and you're trying to write a file inside WAR itself, which is not possible.

Comment: the application is allready deployed as a war file. I seem not to be able to write to this file. I can write to the /bin folder because Tomcat runs in this environment but Ic ant access the path which should be there because I have read from it a few seconds ago! Ive read from 'pathToDBFile' but I cannot write to it? Crazy I tell you -.-

Comment: You're not reading from the file system, you're using ClassLoader to read from WAR file. Difference is this method is reading from WAR archive, if you try to read using `FileInputStream` then you should get the same exception.

Comment: @11thdimension new File() doesnt care if it exists it should make a new one if it doesnt. So it seems that I cannot write where I want to?

Comment: Unless it's the leading /

Comment: `new File()` won't create a file unless you call `.createNewFile()` on it, even then it won't create the recursive path to the file if path doesn't exist.

Comment: So it tells that it doesnt exist because I cant access it? Is there any way that I could write to this file? In my eclipse maven project the File resides under "target/songWebstore/WEB_INF/classes/de/songs.json"

Comment: Resources are not files, and paths to resources are not filenames.

Comment: I found the error: My tomcat folder was in C:Programs once moved outside it worked just fine

Answer (score 2):

You are reading a file which lives in a WAR file. It depends on your tomcat configuration whether the WARs are expanded or not. This means for you: you can NOT rely on any of your web content to be writable.
But you can copy this file to a work directory and start working on it there. As you might know, every servlet context gets its own dedicated temporary work directory:

```
servletContext.getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR);
```

It survives server restarts, but it can be purged if necessary. If you need something more permanent, you need to specify the location yourself.

Comment: Im sorry had to remove your answer as right, although tis not completely wrong what you said

Comment: no worries - just let me know if you find anything wrong about what I wrote.